# Uniformly convergent series of functions: A converse to Abel's criterion?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $f_1, f_2, \ldots: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions, where $D$ is a compact subset of some metric space.

Assume that there is a function $g: D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily continous a priori) such that

$$\tag{1} R_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \ \longrightarrow \ g \quad \text{ pointwise on $D$ $\quad$ (as $n\rightarrow\infty$)}.$$

Suppose further that there is a constant $c\in(0,1)$ such that

$$\tag{2} S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n c^i\cdot f_i \quad \text{ converges uniformly on $D$ $\quad$ (as $n\rightarrow\infty$)}.$$

**Question:** Are (1) and (2) enough to conclude that in fact $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R_n = g$ *uniformly on $D$*?

If necessary, it may be assumed that the $f_i$ are all non-negative.

(Any hints, references or counterexamples are appreciated; this is not a homework question.)

Comment: The answer is no. Find $R_n$ such that $\| R_n-g\|_\infty=1\ \forall n$ and $\|f_i\|_\infty=2\ \forall n$, then you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $D=[0,1]$ and
$$
R_n(x) = \begin{cases}nx & x\leq1/n \\ 2-nx, & 1/n<x\leq2/n, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$

Then $R_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $g(x)=0$ but $\|R_n-g\|_\infty=1$ for every $n$.

Moreover, $\|f_n\|_\infty=\|R_n-R_{n-1}\|_\infty\leq 2$, therefore $S_n$ converges absolutely (hence uniformly) for every $c\in(0,1)$.